# How to return value AND promise in Protractor framework

Tags: return, promise, protractor

let us suggest the function _headerSave() save to DB some Text header. We need to know both the Header and operate the correspond promise.
How could we do it?

Wrong code example:

```
header = headerCreate(); //header is the promise but real header needed

function headerCreate(){
    var header_name = "Random Header Created";
    return _headerSave(header_name); //return promise
}

function _headerSave(header_name){
  element(by.css('button[ng-click="HeaderEditCtrl.saveHeader(true)"]')).click().then(function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('button in modal.buttons')).get(1).click(); //press Save
    browser.driver.wait( function(){
      return element(by.css('table[class="grid-table"] span[title="'+header_name+'"]')).isPresent();
    }, 5000);
  });
  return element(by.css('table[class="grid-table"] span[title="'+header_name+'"]'));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean value _and_ promise? Return value _in_ the promise. If necessary return multiple promises...

Answer (score 2):

Promises are objects.
Objects in JavaScript can have properties. You can add those properties dynamically.

```
function _headerSave(header_name){
  // ...
  var p = element(by.css('table[class="grid-table"] span[title="'+header_name+'"]'));
  p.header_name = header_name;
  return p;
}
```

Usage:

```
_headerSave(header_name).header_name;
```

Comment: That's good and it's work, thank you!
But. What if I wish to pass HeaderPromise further? I try to describe by the next mock-code:
_headerCreate().then(function(HeaderPromise){ element(by.css('div')).then(function(){ console.log(HeaderPromise.header_name); }) })_
The _undefined_ value will be shown in the console.

Comment: You have to manually add it to each part of the chain. The alternative is to subclass `Promise` and delegate to `then` but honestly at that point you might as well a library like bluebird that supports context and be over with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix the problem is make the code simpler.
Instead of

```
headerCreate().then(function(HeaderPromise){
element(by.css('div')).then(function(){
console.log(headerPromise.header_name);
});
});
```

better to write:

```
headerPromise=headerCreate();
element(by.css('div'));
console.log(headerPromise.header_name);
```

*theControlFlow* object allows to do it in this way.